# How to provide input to batch file from a text file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a batch file(install.bat which i use to insatll my application) which prompts user with few questions like 'To accept licencse agreement click y/n'.So what i was thinking to provide the answers from a text file.
i have Created a text file with the answers (e.g. answers.txt):

```
 y
 n
 y
 y
```

i have Created a wrapper batch file that runs my installation batch and redirects its input from the answers file (wrapper.bat):

```
@echo off
install.bat < answers.txt
```

is there any thing that i am missing beacuse its not working properly,i am not sure if install.bat taking some null values from the text file.

Comment: Oh, so I see, "its not working properly".  Great.  On Saturdays I am a psycic, so next Saturday I will figure out exactly how "its not working properly" (error messages and everything) and I will let you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

install.bat:

```
set /p a=Alpha
set /p b=Beta
set /p c=Gamma
set /p d=Delta
echo %a%,%b%,%c%,%d%
```

answers.txt:

```
a
b
c
d
```

call it like this:

```
install.bat<answers.txt
```

Comment: Thanks Stephan for your response but i dont want to make any changes to install.bat file.

Comment: it was only meant to be an example - a "dummy-install.bat". If it doesn't work, you'll have to share the applicable parts of your install.bat.

Comment: basically there are two batch files and the first batch file contains the code like this "@echo off
cd bin
call B.bat load-and-start %1" and  the second batch file contains the whole code(and questions) to install our application .